# Create email signature with latest blog post (Outlook, SharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rss, outlook, outlook-2010

Does anyone know of a way to create an Outlook email signature that includes a link to my latest SharePoint blog entry with the blog title text?  I have spent some time looking around but could not find anything that would let me do this, or any code snippets that would get the latest.  Maybe there is a URL parameter or someway to do it via RSS?